# IdentityServer4 FindByNameAsync always null

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

I am using IdentityServer4 v4.1.1 in a .Net Core 3.1 project and having issues with FindByNameAsync - it always returns null.

This works and returns the user:

```
var user = await userStore.Context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.NormalizedUserName == userManager.NormalizeName(model.Username), default(CancellationToken));
```

This does not and returns null:

```
var user = await userStore.FindByNameAsync(userManager.NormalizeName(model.Username));
```

How is this possible?

**Edit (in an effort to show my research):**
The reason I am really confused about this is that I found the following in the .Net Core source: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/EntityFrameworkCore/src/UserStore.cs#L255
It seems like both of these statements should do the exact same thing. I am hoping that someone can explain why they do not.

Comment: Can you confirm that the normalized name supplied in u.NormalizedUserName is the same as the username searched by FindByNameAsync?

Comment: Yes, I literally replaced one line with the other.

Comment: @Carson, I work with bbailes and I can confirm that the username is exactly the same. We've used the user found by the first query to test the FindByNameAsync method and it still fails to find the user.

Comment: Understood, my question is in relation to the values returned by the term "NormalizedName" u.NormalizedUserName would be, I presume, a field in your schema. Are you certain that the FindByNameAsync function is searching that column and not a different one. As I don't see your schema, I'm verifying with you that there isn't a "NormalizedUserName" column and a "Username" column, where the data searched could be the wrong field.

Comment: @Carson, there is both a `UserName` and `NormalizedUserName`. The `UserName` is all lowercase and the `NormalizedUserName` is populated with `userManager.NormalizeName(model.Username).` I've tested both columns, including Normalizing the `model.UserName` as well as not Normalizing it before sending it to `FindByNameAsync`. bbailes also looked at the source code for IdentityServer4 4.1.1 and it shows that the two queries above should be equivalent and that `FindByNameAsync` uses the `NormalizedUserName` column.

Comment: @Carson NormalizedUserName is part of the Identity standard for .Net Core, not some custom field of ours. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identityuser-1.normalizedusername?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @Carson FindByNameAsync takes a parameter called normalizedUsername. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.iuserstore-1.findbynameasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score -1):

I work with @bbales and I finally have figured it out.

We have a class called `MultiTenantIdentityUserStore`, which we use to override a few things to make the app multi-tenant. It wasn't obvious this was being used, unfortunately.

In it, we have a property:

```
public TTenantKey TenantId { get; set; }
```

This is used to override the `Users` public property:

```
public override IQueryable<TUser> Users => base.Users.Where(u => u.TenantId.Equals(TenantId));
```

Once I set the `UserStore.TenantId`, calling `UserStore.Users.ToList()` went from having 0 results to having 13, as expected. For comparison, `UserStore.Context.Users.ToList()` has 22 records, since we are migrating users from an old version of IdentityServer4 to the current version of 4.1.1.

Now using the 2nd query above returns a user:

```
var user = await userStore.FindByNameAsync(userManager.NormalizeName(model.Username));
```

As an aside, this also makes the `UserManager` and `SignInManager.UserManager` work as expected when using the same methods. (If you didn't know, `UserManager` and `SignInManager.UserManager` are the same object.) This is because the `UserManager` uses the `UserStore` to access the `Users`. When you have dependency injection supply those objects, it's all correctly referencing each other.

It may seem as if this Answer is only for our instance, but with as many unresolved Questions with the same stated problem on this Stack, this might be a widespread problem people aren't catching, or at least aren't updating their Question after figuring it out. I've probably read at least a dozen that don't have Answers. I'm wondering how many of them have our same issue.